# How can I give a service account access to a particular secret?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-secret-manager

I want to grant a service account access to a secret in Google Secrets Manager.

**I** can access the secret like this:

```
gcloud beta secrets versions access 1 --secret="thesecret" --project="myproject"
```

But when my service account tries the same command, gcloud emits this error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.beta.secrets.versions.access) PERMISSION_DENIED: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.

The main question is: **What else do I need to do to ensure that the service account can access the secret?**

---

I have granted that service account "roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor" in Terraform like this:

```
resource google_project_iam_binding the-binding {
  project = myproject
  role = "roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor"
  members = [
    "serviceAccount:theserviceaccount@someotherproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  ]
}
```

And I can verify that it has that role both in the gcp console and like this:

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy myproject  \
--flatten="bindings[].members" \                         
--format='table(bindings.role)' \
--filter="bindings.members:theserviceaccount@someotherproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

    ROLE
    roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor
```

But there's this concept from the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/access-control):

> If a member only needs to access a single secret's value, don't grant that member the ability to access all secrets. For example, you can grant a service account the Secret Accessor role (roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor) on a single secret.

So it's like an iam-policy-binding can have an affinity to a particular secret, but I'm not sure which gcloud commands or terraform resources I can use to create such an affinity.

Comment: `But when my service account tries the same command` - How are you specifying the service account to use? The service account has the correct role, you are probably incorrectly trying to use the service account. For your last question, use the command `gcloud beta secretes add-iam-policy [SECRET-ID] --member=[SERVICE_ACCOUNT] --role={ROLE]` https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/secrets/add-iam-policy-binding

Comment: @JohnHanley you are an incredibly helpful person.  I had encountered one Jenkins agent that was using the desired service account, but subsequent agents weren't.  Explicitly setting the account that I needed got me half way there, and the command you shared command got me the rest of the way.  Thanks.  If you post an answer, I'll accept it.  If not, I'll post one.

Comment: Thank you. I am glad you solved this and posted an answer to benefit everyone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first problem is that I was mistaken about which service account my environment was configured to use.  So I had granted access to the service account, but I wasn't using it after all (apparently they're initialized inconsistently in my case).  I fixed that by running this command before trying to access the secret:

```
gcloud config set account theserviceaccount@someotherproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Also, I didn't realize that there were more than one toplevel gcloud command that let you modify iam policy bindings.  I had been exploring `gcloud iam ...` when what I needed was:

```
gcloud beta secrets add-iam-policy-binding projects/myproject/secrets/mysecret --member serviceAccount:theserviceaccount@someotherproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor
```